# How to neglect a paramter in MongoDB query if the value if null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server, nosql

i would like to fetch document from a products collection in mongoDB based on multiple paramters passed as arguments to the function.

I am using nest js server with mongoose to connect to mongoDB database.

here, in this function i am trying to fetch products where
1.colorCode is equal to conditionCode passed as argument (only if the colorCode passed as argument is not null, if colorCode argument is null - the query should not consider colorCode while fetching data, it should fetch all the documents having colorCode to anything)
2.categoryCode is equal to categoryCode passed as argument (same condition as above).

My function is :

```
async getSearchedProducts(
    title: string,
    category: string,
    brand: string,
    color: string,
    productCode: string,
    sellerCode: string,
    pageNumber: string,
  ) {
    const products = await this.productModel.find({
      colorCode:
        color === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : color,
      categoryCode: category === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : category,
      brandCode: brand === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : brand,
      productCode:
        productCode === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : productCode,
      // brandCode : brand
    });
    return products;
  }
```

desired outcome example :

lets say the products collection is :

```
[
{
"title" : "iphone x",
"colorCode":"black",
"categoryCode":"mobile"
},
{
"title":"MacBook Pro",
"colorCode":"black",
"categoryCode":"laptop"
},
{
"title":"MacBook Air",
"colorCode":"black",
"categoryCode":"laptop"
}
]
```

let assume the function as follow :

```
async getSearchedProducts(
        title: string //is null,
        category: string. //is null,
        color: string, //black
      ) {
        const products = await this.productModel.find({
          colorCode:
            color === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : color,
          categoryCode: category === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : category,
        });
        return products;
      }
```

here desired outcome is :

```
[
    {
    "title" : "iphone x",
    "colorCode":"black",
    "categoryCode":"mobile"
    },
    {
    "title":"MacBook Pro",
    "colorCode":"black",
    "categoryCode":"laptop"
    },
    {
    "title":"MacBook Air",
    "colorCode":"black",
    "categoryCode":"laptop"
    }
    ] - all three documents
```

example 2 :

```
async getSearchedProducts(
        title: string //is null,
        category: string. //laptop,
        color: string, //black
      ) {
        const products = await this.productModel.find({
          colorCode:
            color === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : color,
          categoryCode: category === undefined || 'null' ? { $ne: null } : category,
        });
        return products;
      }
```

here desired outcome is :

```
[
    {
    "title":"MacBook Pro",
    "colorCode":"black",
    "categoryCode":"laptop"
    },
    {
    "title":"MacBook Air",
    "colorCode":"black",
    "categoryCode":"laptop"
    }
    ] - 2 documents
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Abdurrahim Ahmadov. The problem here is my ternary operators in the mongoDB query are not executing and it is simply returning all the documents from collection.

Comment: i mean if the brand passed in argument is 'samsung'. it is also returning the documents with brand 'apple' as well.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you for making time to help me out.

Comment: Ok , I understood,

Comment: brandCode:
          brand != undefined && brand != 'null'
            ? { $eq: brand }
            : { $ne: null},

Comment: Thank you, somehow i am able to get the desired outcome. but, in above code i used {$ne : null} at end, it is returning only documents where the brandCode exists and not equal to null, but i get the documents even if brandCode does not exists and equal to null

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in ternary operator and fixed it as follows:

```
async getSearchedProducts(
        title: string //is null,
        category: string. //laptop,
        color: string, //black
      ) {
        const products = await this.productModel.find({
          colorCode:
           typeof color === 'undefined' || color === null ? { $ne: null } : color,
          categoryCode: typeof category === 'undefined' || category === null ? { $ne: null } : category,
        });
        return products;
      }
```